# Thymeleaf заменить содержимое тега

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Создаю страницу с таблицей, которая заполняется из БД.
Справа каждой строки отображается иконка статуса заказа:

```
<i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
```

Как с помощью Thymeleaf можно задать условие, чтобы менялся тег с содержимым?
Например если

boolean a = true; появлялся

```
<i class="fas fa-check"></i>
```

если false;

```
<i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует несколько методов решения вашей задачи, вклучая решение данное @Komdosh. Например можно добавить решение с использованием  [th:class](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions)...

```
<i th:class="${a? 'fas fa-check' : 'fas fa-eye'}"></i>
```

Но самое лучшее на мой взгляд решение с использованиемм [th:classappend](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appending-and-prepending). В этом варианте ваша HTML страничка будет коректно отображаться просто в броузере (design time) и конечно с Thymeleaf (run time) ...

```
 <i class='fas fa-check' th:class="'fas'" th:classappend="${a? 'fa-check' : 'fa-eye'}"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так можно

```
<i th:attr="class=${a? 'fas fa-check' : 'fas fa-eye'}"></i>
```